# Which file should be modified/created to enable OPcache?

Tags: magento2, php-5.6, opcache

Magento strongly recommends PHP OPcache is enabled for performance reasons.
PHP 5.6 with Zend OPcache is installed on my server but i dont know which file should be modified to enable OPcache features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Installation

OpCache is compiled by default on PHP5.5+. However it is disabled by default. In order to start using OpCache in PHP5.5+ you will first have to enable it. To do this you would have to do the following.

Add the following line to your `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension=/full/path/to/opcache.so (nix)
zend_extension=C:\path\to\php_opcache.dll (win)
```

Note that when the path contains spaces you should wrap it in quotes:

```
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP5.5\ext\php_opcache.dll"
```

Also note that you will have to use the `zend_extension` directive instead of the "normal" `extension` directive because it affects the actual Zend engine (i.e. the thing that runs PHP).

## Usage

Currently there are four functions which you can use:

#### [`opcache_get_configuration()`](http://php.net/opcache_get_configuration):

Returns an array containing the currently used configuration OpCache uses. This includes all ini settings as well as version information and blacklisted files.

```
var_dump(opcache_get_configuration());
```

#### [`opcache_get_status()`](http://php.net/opcache_get_status):

This will return an array with information about the current status of the cache. This information will include things like: the state the cache is in (enabled, restarting, full etc), the memory usage, hits, misses and some more useful information. It will also contain the cached scripts.

```
var_dump(opcache_get_status());
```

#### [`opcache_reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php):

Resets the entire cache. Meaning all possible cached scripts will be parsed again on the next visit.

```
opcache_reset();
```

#### [`opcache_invalidate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php):

Invalidates a specific cached script. Meaning the script will be parsed again on the next visit.

```
opcache_invalidate('/path/to/script/to/invalidate.php', true);
```

## Maintenance and reports

There are some GUI's created to help maintain OpCache and generate useful reports. These tools leverage the above functions.

***OpCacheGUI***

<sub>*Disclaimer I am the author of this project*</sub>

Features:

- OpCache status
- OpCache configuration
- OpCache statistics
- OpCache reset
- Cached scripts overview
- Cached scripts invalidation
- Multilingual
- Mobile device support
- Shiny graphs

Screenshots:

[image: status]

[image: cached-scripts]

[image: graphs]

[image: mobilr]

URL: https://github.com/PeeHaa/OpCacheGUI

***opcache-status***

Features:

- OpCache status
- OpCache configuration
- OpCache statistics
- Cached scripts overview
- Single file

Screenshot:

[image: status]

URL: https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status

***opcache-gui***

Features:

- OpCache status
- OpCache configuration
- OpCache statistics
- OpCache reset
- Cached scripts overview
- Cached scripts invalidation
- Automatic refresh

Screenshot:

[image: opcache-gui-overview]

URL: https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui